# URL ReWrite Affecting Page Content

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a website with the following folder structure:

```
website >> magazine >> news
```

Inside `news` my files include:

```
htaccess, updates.php, articles.php & article.php
```

So my `htaccess` looks like:

```
Options -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex updates.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  

RewriteRule ^updates                        updates.php
RewriteRule ^articles                       articles.php

RewriteRule ^updates/([\w-]+)/?$            updates.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9]+)/?$           articles.php?currentpage=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)/?$   article.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

The problem(s) that I have is that when I visit `website.uk/magazine/news/updates/1459967836` it shows the result for my article with ID `1460544406`.

The code in my `updates` page is:

```
...
if(isset($_GET["id"])){$id = $_GET["id"];}else{
$id = "latest";
}
?>
<?php
if ($id == "latest"){$var = "ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 1";}else{$var = "WHERE id = '$id'";}
?>
<?php
$posts_sql = "SELECT * FROM magazine_news_updates $var";
...
```

Does anyone know why when I visit `1459967836` I gewt shown the result for `1460544406`.

Also, when I visit `website.uk/magazine/news/article-add-form.php` I get shown `website.uk/magazine/news/articles`, even though the URL is displayed correctly. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

** SOLVED **

By removing (

```
RewriteRule ^updates                        updates.php
RewriteRule ^articles                       articles.php
```

) the pages now show everything correctly!